# D3 & React - create a scatterplot of images without using xlink:href

Tags: javascript, svg, href, todataurl, xlink

Edit: I've added the serialized SVG to the codepen (not displaying unless you remove the root div) to show that the SVG serialization is working properly. Still not sure why this serialized SVG isnt converting into the data URL like I want...

I have created a React component that takes as an input prop a dataset of statistics, and outputs an interactive scatterplot of sports team logos. Here is an example screenshot of the output:

[image]
And here is a simple (as simple as it could possibly be - i tried my best) reproducible example:

```js
class GraphComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);
  }

  createLogoDefs() {
  // Setup
  let logoRadius = 30;
    let graphData = [
      { teamId: 'DUKE' },
      { teamId: 'UNC' }, 
      { teamId: 'UVA' },
      { teamId: 'TTU' }];

  const svg = d3.select('#mySvg');
  const logoDefs = svg.select('defs.logoDefs');

  graphData.forEach(d => {
   let teamImgSrc = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/' + d.teamId + '-logo.png';
   logoDefs.append('svg:pattern')
    .attr('id', `teamlogo-${d.teamId}`)
    .attr('width', logoRadius)
    .attr('height', logoRadius)
    .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
    .append('svg:image')
    .attr('xlink:href', teamImgSrc)
    .attr('width', logoRadius)
    .attr('height', logoRadius)
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 0);
  });
 }
  
  drawGraph() {
    let graphData = [
      { teamId: 'DUKE', x: 25, y: 35 },
      { teamId: 'UNC', x: 125, y: 50 }, 
      { teamId: 'UVA', x: 225, y: 100 },
      { teamId: 'TTU', x: 225, y: 35 }];
  
    let svg = d3.select('#mySvg');
    const logoMarkers = svg.select('g.points')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(graphData, d => d.teamId);
      
    let logoRadius = 30;
    logoMarkers
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('transform', d => `translate(${d.x}, ${d.y})`)
      .attr('x', 0).attr('y', 0)
      .attr('width', logoRadius)
      .attr('height', logoRadius)
      .attr('fill', d => `url(#teamlogo-${d.teamId})`)
      .attr('cursor', 'pointer');
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createLogoDefs();
    this.drawGraph()
  }
  
 render() {
   return (
      <svg id="mySvg" width='400' height='400'>
        <defs className='logoDefs' />
        <g className="points" />
      </svg>
  )
 }
}

let graphData = 
ReactDOM.render(
  <GraphComponent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' />
```

[Here is a codepen](https://codepen.io/canovice/pen/XvjWLx) to the graph as well.

**My Problem:** I am using Kendo-React-PDF to create a PDF-download tool for my application. To download PDFs, I need to convert the SVGs on my app into images using the following approach:

```
let serializedSvg = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(d3.select('#mySvg').node());
let someCanvas = this.refs.canvas1;
let someContext = someCanvas.getContext('2d');
someContext.drawSvg(serializedHexChart, 0, 0);
let newImgSrc = someCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

Unfortunately, when I do this, the data URL generated is that of a blank image. After extensive debugging, I concluded that the SVG serialization is working, and the serialized SVG is being drawn to the canvas successfully, but the `toDataURL` to get the image source from the canvas **is failing**.

I pinpointed the issue to this line in my graphing component - `.attr('xlink:href', teamImgSrc)`. For whatever reason, `toDataURL` doesn't like the way I'm creating image defs using this attribute, and as a result the entire data URL ends up being a source to a blank image.

**My question:** is then, (a) what's going on here? why doesn't the toDataURL function want to work with the xlink:href attribute?, (b) is there a way to keep xlink:href attribute and still get a viable image src of this SVG graph, and (c) if not, is there another way to draw images onto an SVG that is not this approach that uses image defs, xlink:href, and the subsequent fill using `url(#teamlogo-${d.teamId})`?

Thanks in advance for this!!

**Edit:** below the line `let teamImgSrc = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/cbbteamlogos/' + d.teamId + '-logo.png';` (within the for loop), I added the following code:

```
let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = '800px';
canvas.height = '460px';

let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(teamImgSrc, 0, 0);

let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
console.log('dataURL: ', dataURL);
```

...however this throws the error:

`D3TeamLogos.js:185 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'`

not sure what preprocessing i should do on the image before passing it to the `drawImage` function...

Comment: you need to convert the images to data urls. See the duplicate.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for the direction on this, although I don't see how the question is a duplicate of the other question you've shared, which is with regards to a similar issue but for fonts. 

Is there a simple way to convert the images to data urls in the scope of what I'm trying to do with image defs and images as backgrounds?  Is it a couple lines of codes or a lot of code?

Comment: You use the same method. For that question you convert fonts to data URLs, for this it's images. There's absolutely no difference to what you have to do. It's the difference between painting a shed and a bungalow, in either case you use paint and a paintbrush. If you can paint a shed you can also paint a bungalow.